# Check if text is egual to "x" speech_recognition Python

Tags: python, if-statement, speech-recognition

I'm working with speech_recognition python and I want to know if It's possible to check if the text that I've said is egual to "x"
Here is my code :

```py
import speech_recognition
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

while True:

    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:

            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
            text = text.lower()

            print(text)

    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError():
        print("I don't understand sir")
        continue
```

I've checked

```py
if (text == "x"):
```

But it didn't works

Comment: could you log the output of `text` so we can see what's in that variable?

Comment: You can first `print(text)` to see what you get.

Comment: It print what I say, this work but I just don't know how to check what Am i saying to change the result

Comment: Please show us a code where you put the line `if (text == "x"):`

Comment: Then you write all that you say in lower case. E,g. Imagine you say **Come here**, you already made text lowercase so now you can check by `if text == "come here":` then `print("ok")`